# salt pkg.upgrade misses some updates

Tags: linux, upgrade, saltstack

If I execute `apt upgrade` several packages will be found:

```
# apt upgrade
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-109 linux-headers-4.4.0-109-generic linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

If I do the same thing through `salt`, the output will be empty

```
# salt 'target' pkg.upgrade
```

**Is there a correct way to carry out a full update of the system?**